# Reassign approval request in Apex

Tags: apex, approval-process

I have a scenario where I want to 'reassign' the approval request to a certain user if a certain condition is fulfilled.

Also during the reassignment I want to update Comments that would be readable in the Approval History section on the page layouts.

I want to achieve this specifically through Apex.

I have looked at ProcessSteps object that gives me the Comments field, but that is locked for updation.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the approval step using the `ActorId` property of `ProcessInstanceWorkItem` object. Unfortunately as you said, comments are readonly and according to [this thread](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Gp0TAAS) it's not going to change soon.

There only workaround I can imagine would be to create custom history list and manage it by your own.

Comment: I found the same thing, Bart.... Unfortunate.